# NGRX: how to subscribe the result from a selector with both sync or async function

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

I want to subscribe the change of a field in the state and trigger some async function to make an http call. However, seems like the `subscribe()` function is a sync function, how can I call an async function in it?

The code I am having is as follow:

```
store.select('fieldA').subscribe((fieldAValue) => {
    this.callHttpEndpoint(fieldAValue);
});
```

what I am looking for is

```
store.select('fieldA').subscribe(async (fieldAValue) => {
    await this.callHttpEndpoint(fieldAValue);
});
```

How can I call a async function in subscribe? Thank you

Comment: both snippets you show should pretty much work already work as you want. What is the issue you are facing?

Comment: Hi @TobiasS. with the first snippet, if I would like to do something more after the callHttpEndpoint function, then the callHttpEndpoint does not block before it's finished. Is it correct?

Answer (score 1):

There are potentially lots of options here.

Maybe you are in the context of an `async` function and you want to work with Promises. In that case, use [`firstValueFrom`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/firstValueFrom). (note that you will only get the first emitting value from the store)

```
const fieldAValue = await firstValueFrom(store.select('fieldA'))
await this.callHttpEndpoint(fieldAValue);
```

---

It would probably be beneficial to do it the *RxJS*-way and use Observables instead. In that case, chain multiple Observables/Promises together in a [`switchMap`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/switchMap).

```
store.select('fieldA').pipe(
  switchMap(fieldAValue => this.callHttpEndpoint(fieldAValue))
).subscribe(result => {
  // process your results here
})
```

---

Generally speaking, your code works too.

```
store.select('fieldA').subscribe(async (fieldAValue) => {
  const result = await this.callHttpEndpoint(fieldAValue);
 
  // process result here
});
```

The code *would* wait for the result of the http call. But it might not be considered *best practice*.

Comment: Hi @Tobias S., does it mean when the callHttpEndpoint is called in `switchMap`, the `subscribe` function will not be triggered until `callHttpEndpoint` is finished. is it correct?

Comment: @Ben - thats correct

Comment: Thank you @Tobias S., let me give it a try.